# parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WindowsFormsApplication8.receipt>' is less accessible than method

Tags: c#

List _list;
        string _total, _cash, _change, _date;

```
public Form8(List<receipt> datasource, string total, string cash, string change, string date)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _list = datasource;
    _total = total;
    _cash = cash;
    _change = change;
    _date = date;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJJPU.png)

Here I got an error.

> Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is less accessible than method 'WindowsFormsApplication8.Form8.Form8(System.Collections.Generic.List, string, string, string, string)' C:\Users\thush\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication8\WindowsFormsApplication8\Form8.cs 18 16 WindowsFormsApplication8

Comment: Most likely the type `receipt` is not public. Make it public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you've created your own `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` class, the error is specifically referring to your `receipt` class.  Note the accessibility of where it's being used:

```
public Form8(List<receipt> ...
```

This is in turn part of a `public` class (`Form8`).  So the error is telling you that these things are more accessible than the types you're requiring in them, specifically `receipt`.

From the perspective of consuming code, any code can see your `Form8` class and can see its constructor.  But if that same consuming code *can't* see the `receipt` class, then that constructor would make no sense.  The compiler prevents this by the error you're seeing.

In short, if you want to use `receipt` in a `public` way like this, then `receipt` itself needs to be `public`.

So basically just as your `Form8` class is `public`:

```
public partial class Form8 : Form
{
    //...
```

So must your `receipt` class be:

```
public class receipt
{
    //...
```

(Mostly guessing as to the declaration of the `receipt` class, since you don't show it.)

Comment: @tagon: I've updated the answer with an example.  You just need to make the class `public` in order to use it publicly.